# JavaScript function uses simply "true". How does this work in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

This is simply a form. The code tests if all the required fields a filled in. Specifically, I don't understand the test on the keyup. What is it testing? Simply is something is typed into the input field?

```
<p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="required">
    <span>Please enter your name</span>
</p>

<p class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn-submit">
</p>

<script>
    var $submit = $(".submit input");

    function requiredFilledIn() {
        if(true) $submit.attr("disabled", "disabled");
        else $submit.removeAttr("disabled");
    }

    $("#form span").hide();

    $("input, textarea").focus(function () {
        $(this).next().fadeIn("slow");
    }).blur(function(){
        $(this).next().fadeOut("slow");
    }).keyup(function(){
        //Check all required fields.
        requiredFilledIn();
    });

    $("#email").onkeyup(function(){
        if (true) $(this).next().removeClass("error").addClass("valid");
        else $(this).next().removeClass("valid").addClass("error");
    });

    requiredFilledIn();        
</script>
```

Comment: At quick glance, this code appears to disable any input fields under the `submit` class.  Though it does it rather round-about.  The if/else is clearly extraneous and the `keyup` is pointless because `requireFilledIn()` disables the inputs so input cannot occur.

Comment: The `else` never executes. This is sometimes used as a way to "comment" out code without actually using comments (maybe the author's IDE can fold else blocks better etc..). Sometimes the `true` is generated by a templating language server side so in the Perl/Python/PHP/Ruby code you can enable/disable certain features of the script.